# How to find the JMX port of a remote machine using Java

Tags: java, cassandra, jmx

I am currently developing a tool that can remotely repair and compact a node in a Cassandra cluster. I realize that in order to accomplish this I need to have the IP address and the JMX port to access that node remotely.

Although we have defined a default JMX port, but we also allow users to change that port manually. Since that node is not local, I cannot fetch the port number simply using System.getProperty(). When nodes in the cluster have different JMX port number, it seems impossible to access other nodes via JMX.

Is there a way to get the JMX port number from another node using just Java?

If this is not possible, is there a way to repair and compact a remote Cassandra node without knowing that node's JMX port.

Comment: The short answer is "no" unless you are running the RMI registry on a standard port.  There is no way remotely to know which RMI registry port has been used.

Comment: http://www.jolokia.org/features/proxy.html might help, but it's still not going to 'discover'.

Comment: Also, from the Cassandra side, it's not currently possible to inspect the bound JMX port over the Thrift interface. Is there a reason you can't just expect your users to do the appropriate configuration in your app if they change the default jmx port?

Comment: So fix the JMX port solves everything.....